# How to get around swig warning 518 with Char and UCHAR

Tags: c#, c++, swig

The C++ API I am wrapping contains Char and CHAR as well as UChar and UCHAR typedefs. Swig understandably complains with warning 518:

warning 518: Portability warning: File SWIGTYPE_p_UChar.cs will be overwritten by SWIGTYPE_p_UCHAR.cs on case insensitive filesystems such as Windows' FAT32 and NTFS unless the class/module name is renamed

same for Char and CHAR. I tried to get around this with three approaches:

1. %ignore CHAR; %ignore UCHAR
2. %rename (CHAR_) CHAR; %rename (UCHAR_) UCHAR; and some similar variations
3. %apply UCHAR { UChar }; %apply %apply UCHAR* { UChar* }; same with CHAR, several variations

None of them were working. How can I get around the case-sensitivity-clash here?

Thank You!

Comment: The `rename` directive needs to be before the types in question are ever seen. This would make renaming a built-in type difficult / impossible. So you'll need to rename the one which is not built-in.

Comment: The ignore and apply cant work. But the rename should do the trick: it affects the generated file name. It only affects function declarations that come after it, so long as you were careful about that, it should work. I think you need to show minimal .i  that reproduces problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. After finding out that another problem intermixed with the case problem described here, I managed to make the %rename approach work for me.